# Number of solution of the equation $ (6m+1)^2+3(6n+1)^2=4p $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

i am reading the book an introduction to non abelian class field theory  by Seiken Saito and Toyokazu Hiramatsu in page 5 ,and i am stuck in the following part

let

$\eta(6z)\eta(18z)=\sum_{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}} (-1)^{n+m} q^{((6m+1)^2+3(6n+1)^2)/4)}$
Where $q=e^{2\pi iz}$

and let  A(p) be the number of solution$(m,n)$ of
$\begin{equation}
(6m+1)^2+3(6n+1)^2=4p   \quad(1)
\end{equation}
$

then

I)$A(p)=2$  and n+m is even if $p=x^2+27y^2$

II)$A(p)=1$ and   n+m is odd if $p\neq x^2+27y^2$

Questions

i don't understand how they got the values of $A(p)$,and why they considered the binary quadratic form    $x^2+27y^2 $?

my attempt
from equation (1) by putting x=6m+1
and y=6n+1 the question is equivalent to

$x^2+3y^2=4p $

and by a familiar result from the theory of binary quadratic form ,the previous equation has a solution iff  $z^2 \equiv -12 [4p]$ is solvable which is equivalent to $z^2 \equiv -3 mod p $ is solvable  i,e $ \left( \frac{-3}{p} \right)=1$
it has solution when $p \equiv 1 [3]$
and we know that the number of equivalent class of binary quadratic forms of Discrimant $-12 $ is 1 since the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-12})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3}) $ is 1, so we can consider only the quadratic form $x^2+3y^2$ .
but i don't know how to go further.

Comment: exercise in Introduction to the Theory of Numbers by Dickson(1929), number 4 on page 81; if $m$

Comment: @WillJagy I don't have the book can you explain the idea of the proof

Comment: your chapter:  https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/suppl/10.1142/10096/suppl_file/10096_chap01.pdf

Comment: download Dickson here. https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.466075

Comment: @WillJagy the link for Dickson book is not working, and I link before it was not helpful.

Comment: I printed out pages 3,4,5....   This is in Ireland and Rosen. Chapter 9 is called Cubic and Biquadratic Reciprocity. Section 6 is The Cubic Character of $2.$   Meanwhile, suggest you read  Hudson and Williams   http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf   The business about the cube root of $2$  and $x^2 + 27 y^2$  is due to Gauss.

Answer (score 0):

pages 80, 81 from Dickson (1929), Introduction to the Theory of Numbers

[image]

[image]

Comment: does the formula for E is $E=\sum_{\mu | m} (-1)^{\frac{1}{2}(\mu-1)}$

Comment: @AsterPhoenix  the particular $E(n)$ used (in exercise 4) is defined in exercise 2